# Compare Two PHP Strings

Tags: php, string

I would like to implement a function that compares 2 strings and displays the different words with a different background (such as green if text is added or red if text is deleted).

This function would be similar to the difference between the original topic and the edited one on StackOverflow.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a pure-PHP implementation here:
[Text version-control in PHP with difference highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358114/text-version-control-in-php-with-difference-highlight/5358138#5358138)

Answer (score 0):

You can use already written [wdiff](http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/)

Comment: I don't see it say anything about PHP...?

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: you can run it from php using `system()` or `exec()`

Comment: @Christian Sciberras: you did not mention OS in your question. We can always find some case which any answer doesn't fit in. I'd prefer using that tool since it works, works fine and fast.

Comment: Though I've increasingly used native apps from PHP, I've always tried to put a limit. The OP's question is one such example, why would I rely on a black box (GNU with all of it's open source merits, is still a black box) and risk many disadvantages such as deployment issues? Now if the OP *did* ask for speed, I *would* suggest a native tool. Sounds way overkill for a 50-liner if you ask me...